# Trying to publish the Web API in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create the Website in the IIS from the WEB API that has been created in the Visual Studio. I published the web API from the Visual studio in to File System in the Local folder. And tried creating the web site 
[image]

I avoided the warning and tried to browse through the site it throws error like
[image]

I am not sure what I am missing. Is there something i need to give access. The IUSR and IIS_iUSRS has access to the folder which has the published application

Comment: are you using windows authentication or Forms ? and post your server configuration as snapshot. 
Application Pool -> select pool -> right click -> advance settings.

Comment: also share the authentication mode of server.